# Sudden SVN performance degradation with VisualSVN locally

Tags: performance, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a SVN server instance set up on my desktop for the purposes of demonstrating the many benefits of SVN/TortoiseSVN.

Performance has today degrading significantly however when performing actions such as viewing the logs etc. This isn't ideal for a demonstration, given that a "Show Log" operation now takes approx 5seconds, whereas before it was sub-second response.

The puzzling thing is this performance degradation only seems to have come about after I performed the following actions:

- changed password for one user (myself)
- created a second user
- created a 2nd repository on the server

Note, after changing the password for the user I had issues with certificates, so I cleaned all Tortoise caches.

To attempt to resolve the problem I have :

- cleared all TortoiseSVN Settings-Saved Data including cached authentication data.
- I have also cleared the cached logs
- dropped the new second repository.
- reboot

To no avail.

Information that might be pertinent:

- One repository.
- Hosted locally.
- Repository security is managed by VisualSVN. Everyone has R/W access.
- Main repository only consists of ~30MB/600 files.
- Repository has only had ~50 revisions.

VisualSVN properties:

- Automatically adjust permissions: Enabled
- Use Secure Connection: Enabled
- Server Binding - All IP Addresses
- Certificate is in date
- Authentication is Subversion
- No special logging other than Event Log

Event log shows nothing unusual.

If no response then tomorrow I might try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) by Sysinternals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be completely unrelated but after a recent password change by one of our users, Commit Monitor was spamming the server with access attempts.  It was leading to performance degradation that was noticeable.

Comment: I haven't seen this occur again, but have accepted your answer.